# Visual basic - Runtime Error - '2047023170(800706be)'

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation, whatsapp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64n2f.png)I am doing WhatsApp automation. The visual basic code was working fine but now I am facing automation error. When I run the macros code it shows **Runtime Error - '2047023170(800706be)'**, the remote procedure call fails.

My code is as following:

```
Sub WhatsAppAuto()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim strip As String
Dim strPhoneNumber As String
Dim strMessage As String
Dim strPostData As String
Dim IE As Object

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

    strPhoneNumber = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
    strMessage = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
    
       
'IE.navigate "whatsapp://send?phone=phone_number&text=your_message"
       
        strPostData = "whatsapp://send?phone=" & strPhoneNumber & "&text=" & strMessage
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        **IE.navigate strPostData**
       
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
```

In this code, its showing error on the line - "IE.navigate strPostData"

I have been stuck on this error and I am not able to find any solution.

Comment: Did your whatsapp account get suspended?

Comment: No, my WhatsApp is working fine.

Comment: This issue may be related to permissions, have you loged in OS as an administrator? And you could also try to disable Protected Mode in ie. In `tools` -> `Interner Options` -> `Security` ->uncheck `Enable Protected Mode`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but its still showing the same error.

Comment: Type `services.msc` in the windows command to check whether the `remote procedure call` service is enabled. By the way, is there same issue when navigating to a public webpage E.g. www.google.com?

Comment: The remote procedure call service is already running. No, there is no issue in navigating to a webpage.